# Can I use a function in assembly language to randomly fill my table that I printed in text mode with letters?

Tags: assembly, random

This is my code, i don't know if there is a fuction or something like that which I can use to fill in the table random letters? (It prints a table with spaces in each index of the table, there is something I can use or to replace all the spaces with a letter or do same loop for the space generating but with random letters?

```
IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h
DATASEG
TimesToPrintCol db 7
TimesToPrintRow db 6
TimesToPrintNewRow db 6
TimesToPrintStart db 25
TimesToPrintSpace db 6
NumOfTimesSpace db 9
NumOfTimesCol db 9
NumOfTimesRow db 9
```

CODESEG

```
start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    mov ax, 13h
    int 10h
PrintStart:
    xor cx, cx
    mov cl, [TimesToPrintStart]
    cmp cx, 0
    je NewLine
    sub [TimesToPrintStart], 1
    mov dl,'_'
    mov ah , 2
    int 21h
    jmp PrintStart
NewLine:
    mov dl,10
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h
    mov dl, 13
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h
    xor cx, cx
PrintCol:
    xor cx, cx
    mov cl, [TimesToPrintCol]
    cmp cx, 0
    je PrintLineCol
    sub [TimesToPrintCol], 1
    mov dl,'|'
    mov ah , 2
    int 21h
    jmp PrintRow
PrintSpace:
    xor cx, cx
    mov cl, [TimesToPrintSpace]
    cmp cx, 0
    je PrintLineCol
    sub [TimesToPrintSpace], 1
    mov dl,' '
    mov ah , 2
    int 21h
    jmp PrintNewRow
PrintRow:
    xor cx, cx
    mov cl, [TimesToPrintRow]
    cmp cx, 0
    je PrintLineRow
    sub [TimesToPrintRow], 1
    mov dl,'_'
    mov ah , 2
    int 21h
    jmp PrintSpace
PrintLineCol:
    mov dl,10
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h
    mov dl, 13
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h
    xor cx, cx
    mov cl, [NumOfTimesCol]
    cmp cx, 0
    je PrintLineRow
    sub [NumOfTimesCol], 1
    add [TimesToPrintCol], 7
    add [TimesToPrintRow], 6
    add [TimesToPrintSpace], 6
    jmp PrintCol
PrintNewRow:
    xor cx, cx
    mov cl, [TimesToPrintNewRow]
    cmp cx, 0
    je PrintLineCol
    sub [TimesToPrintNewRow], 1
    mov dl,'_'
    mov ah , 2
    int 21h
    jmp PrintCol
PrintLineRow:
    mov dl,10
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h
    mov dl, 13
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h
    xor cx, cx
    mov cl, [NumOfTimesRow]
    cmp cx, 0
    je exit
    sub [NumOfTimesRow], 1
    add [TimesToPrintCol], 7
    add [TimesToPrintRow], 6
    add [TimesToPrintSpace], 6
    add [TimesToPrintNewRow] , 6
    jmp PrintCol
exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
END start
```

Comment: With 'function', do you mean an `int` call which returns a random number? (Not that I know - and certainly not in a valid ASCII range.) Or do you want to *call* a function to change the space in your `mov dl, ' '` line to something random? ...Yes, that is possible.

Comment: yes i want to change the '   ' to a random letter (i dont really care if its an int call or calling a function i just need it to work

Comment: Intel has instruction RDRAND DX which fills DL with random number 0..255 but this is not available on every computer. Perhaps you could define a static array, filled with random letters by hand, and load DL from that array sequentialy.